# Getting XML node text with VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript

Doing a VBScript that should parse XML and get some info, here's an example of XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<Performance>
    <Group>EX-007
        <Student>
            <Name>testname</Name><ID>12345</ID>
                <Subject>Informatics
                    <Semester>1<Mark>
                        <Exam>5</Exam>
                    </Mark></Semester></Subject>
                <Subject>Phys
                    <Semester>2<Mark>
                        <PersonalTask>4</PersonalTask>
                        <Exam>3</Exam>
                    </Mark></Semester></Subject>
        </Student>
    </Group>
</Performance>
```

This is the VBScript code:

```vb
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml.DOMDocument")
success = xml.Load("data1.xml")
Set root = xml.DocumentElement
Set nodes = root.SelectNodes("Group")
WScript.Echo(nodes(0).text)
```

I would like to get an "EX-007" output in console, but instead it outputs the whole tree under the group tag. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not well-designed, because some of your nodes contain both text and child nodes. You could work around that by replacing the text from the child node(s):

```vb
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^\s+|\s+$"

For Each node In xml.SelectNodes("//Group")
    txt = Replace(node.text, node.SelectSingleNode("./Student").text, "")
    WScript.Echo re.Replace(txt)
Next
```

However, a better solution would be to structure your XML data properly, e.g. by moving the nested text to attributes of their node:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<Performance>
    <Group Name="EX-007">
        <Student>
            <Name>testname</Name>
            <ID>12345</ID>
            <Subject Title="Informatics">
                <Semester Number="1">
                    <Mark>
                        <Exam>5</Exam>
                    </Mark>
                </Semester>
            </Subject>
            <Subject Title="Phys">
                <Semester Number="2">
                    <Mark>
                        <PersonalTask>4</PersonalTask>
                        <Exam>3</Exam>
                    </Mark>
                </Semester>
            </Subject>
        </Student>
    </Group>
</Performance>
```

so that you can select the information directly, like this:

```vb
For Each node In xml.SelectNodes("//Group/@Name")
    WScript.Echo node.text
Next
```